# Send email from Oracle 12c with postfix on Oracle Linux 7

Tags: gmail, oracle12c, rhel7, postfix-mta

I have postfix service on my Oracle Linux and they work well done.
I use function

```
create or replace procedure Send_Mail(Msg_To varchar2, Msg_Subject varchar2, Msg_Text varchar2) is
    c        Utl_Smtp.Connection;
    Rc       integer;
    Msg_From varchar2(50) := 'me@me.com'; -- email of my company which hosted on Gmail
    Mailhost varchar2(30) := 'smtp.gmail.com';

begin
    c := Utl_Smtp.Open_Connection(Mailhost, 587);
    Utl_Smtp.Helo(c, Mailhost);
    Utl_Smtp.StartTLS(c);
    Utl_Smtp.Mail(c, Msg_From);
    Utl_Smtp.Rcpt(c, Msg_To);

    Utl_Smtp.Data(c,
                  'From: Oracle Database' || Utl_Tcp.Crlf || 'To: ' || Msg_To || Utl_Tcp.Crlf || 'Subject: ' || Msg_Subject || Utl_Tcp.Crlf ||
                  Msg_Text);
    Utl_Smtp.Quit(c);

exception
    when Utl_Smtp.Invalid_Operation then
        Dbms_Output.Put_Line(' Invalid Operation in Mail attempt 
using UTL_SMTP.');
    when Utl_Smtp.Transient_Error then
        Dbms_Output.Put_Line(' Temporary e-mail issue - try again');
    when Utl_Smtp.Permanent_Error then
        Dbms_Output.Put_Line(' Permanent Error Encountered.');
end;
```

which I found on http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_utl_smtp_utility.htm

when I run function

```
BEGIN
send_mail(msg_to      => 'me@me.com',
          msg_subject => 'Test subject',
          msg_text    => 'Test text');
END;
```

I get a error:

```
ORA-29279: SMTP permanent error: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. im3sm2477330wjb.13 - gsmtp /* 132/5 selected symbols */
```

what I did wrong or what I must do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is mentioned in the documentation, which also tells you [how to secure the SMTP connection using SSL/TLS](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_smtp.htm#ARPLS73117). You need to call `utl_smtp.starttls()`.

```
...
begin
    c := Utl_Smtp.Open_Connection(Mailhost, 587);
    Utl_Smtp.Ehlo(c, Mailhost);
    Utl_Smtp.StartTLS(c);
    Utl_Smtp.Ehlo(c, Mailhost);
    Utl_Smtp.Mail(c, Msg_From);
    Utl_Smtp.Rcpt(c, Msg_To);
    ...
```

Comment: Thank You, @AlexPoole, but now it is ORA-29279: SMTP permanent error: 503 5.5.1 EHLO/HELO first. r7sm3173844wjp.43 - gsmtp

Comment: OK, so do an `ehlo` call first. The docs also say you need to reissue that afterwards, though their example doesn't. You may need to supply more arguments to the `open_connection` call, as shown in the docs too.

Comment: I rewrite code in question and now i have, PLS-00905: object SYS.SEND_MAIL is invalid /* ; = #59 */

Comment: Please don't edit the question to something that no longer shows the error you originally asked about. You should not be creating your procedure in the SYS schema, or any other built-in schema. You can `show errors` or query the `user_errors` view to see what is wrong with the procedure. but you seem to have invented a `utl_smtp.set_wallet` procedure, rather than using the arguments in `open_connection()`?

Comment: Sorry, my falth, is utl_http.set_wallet, and now ORA-29024: Certificate validation failure

Comment: `c := Utl_Smtp.Open_Connection(Mailhost, 587);
    Utl_Http.set_wallet('file:/home/oracle/Wallet/gmailcom/', 'password');
    Utl_Smtp.Helo(c, Mailhost);
    Utl_Smtp.StartTLS(c);
    Utl_Smtp.Mail(c, Msg_From);
    Utl_Smtp.Rcpt(c, Msg_To);`

Comment: That's a completely different issue, so you should ask a new question (if you can't find an existing one). Why aren't you setting the wallet in the open call though? I'm not even sure whether one set by utl_http is in scope for utl_smtp.

Comment: OK, Thank You, @AlexPoole.